# Page does not show image

Tags: html, css, sass

The problem is that I have a div class 'breadcam_bg' with a url of an image. And in my console, page sees the div, but does not display image

**html**

```
    <div class="bradcam_area breadcam_bg">  This div!
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-12">
                    <div class="bradcam_text">
                        <h3>Contact</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**style.css**

```
.breadcam_bg {
  background-image: url(blog/static/blog/img/banner/banner.png);
}
```

**_bradcam.scss**

```
.breadcam_bg{
    background-image: url(blog/static/blog/img/banner/banner.png);
}
```

I guess the url is correct, so I have no idea what is the problem about

Comment: Your `url()` values are currently relative to the path of the `.css` file - but you should make it a root-relative URI to eliminate that as a cause.

Comment: Check the console and network tabs of your browser's dev tools to see what errors there are

Answer (score 1):

The URL to the image must be written in "".

```
.breadcam_bg {
  background-image: url("blog/static/blog/img/banner/banner.png");
}
```

should work then, otherwise you should check if the url is correct and if the page can access the image

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code on my system with my own image it seems to work fine for me
I think the issue is with the url try putting the root url

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
    .breadcam_bg {
  background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/564x/20/0c/54/200c54a0baafda5d7f2395da28ec3e97.jpg");
}
</style>
<body>
    <div class="bradcam_area breadcam_bg">  This div!
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-12">
                    <div class="bradcam_text">
                        <h3>Contact</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the quotes around your image and it's locating to the correct folder where your image is.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .breadcam_bg {
         background-image: url("blog/static/blog/img/banner/banner.png");
        }

        .breadcam_bg{
        background-image: url("blog/static/blog/img/banner/banner.png");
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="bradcam_area breadcam_bg">  This div!
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-12">
                    <div class="bradcam_text">
                        <h3>Contact</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```